# Video site with HTML5 embed support?

Tags: webapp-rec, video, html5

YouTube, Vimeo and presumably others support html5 video when played back on their own sites - but it's still strictly flash for embedded video played on 3rd party sites.

Are there any video sites out there that support embedded html5 video playback?

Comment: Surely to embed HTML5 into another site that site has to be written in or support HTML5. Or am I missing something?

Comment: you are missing something - HTML5 is a client side technology.

Comment: exactly. And so, if a site has an HTML4 doctype and you try to embed HTML5 video, then it won't work.

Comment: none of which is relevant to the question I've asked.

Comment: Basically what he's saying is that if you embed a YouTube video into your own website, it will use Flash. He's asking if there are any video services that allow you to embed their videos into your own website **using HTML5** instead of Flash.

Answer (score 3):

Vimeo has a Universal Player;

http://vimeo.com/blog:334

> Instead of being a direct link to a Flash player the new Universal Player can automatically detect what kind of device is viewing the video and choose the optimum player based on the device's capabilities.

Hope this helps.